# Creating a Java program to compile a source file using cmd

Tags: java, windows, compilation, cmd, processbuilder

I am working on something which requires me to use cmd for compiling my source files. I am a java novice i have been trying to find out a way to compile my source files using cmd as we know that we can compile, see output and errors on cmd. A lot of search and efforts have brought me on the conclusion that using ProcessBuilder class i can manipulate running cmd. I need a bit guidance on the process through which i am able to make a Java program which can command compilation, read output and errors back. I have been thinking of reading and writing from cmd, if there is any other way more efficient than this, please do guide.

Comment: There are powerful build tools that can be used outside of IDE (if so required).  Why do you need to write your own?

Comment: My purpose is not compilation. Rather it is simplification of the process, i do not agree with what we currently have but i am a novice and hence am just starting. If i can use some build tools in java please do tell.

Answer (score 0):

The windows cmd utility really is not user friendly.

May I suggest using Windows PowerShell instead, so that you shouldn't need to run a javafile to compile one.

Assuming you have java installed correctly and you can open PoewrShell successfully using the start menu search, all you need to do is 

`cd C:\Path\To\Folder\With\Java\Source\Files
javac YourJavaSource.java`

Comment: I thought he was asking what you're answering at first as well, but he actually wants to write a Java program that compiles another Java program.

Comment: Exactly Sir. That is what i wish to do if a way is possible.

Answer (score 0):

@AHM If you are programming on Windows operating system, please install the relevant JDK on your system like 64bit or 32bit and then set path in environment variables, Open cmd prompt and change directory to where you have created that java program and use the command javac Sample1.java , Which will compile and create the .class file in same directory if no errors, and run your program using the command "java classname" (without any extinctions)

Comment: I know these things i wish to manipulate these tasks without opening cmd.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html, you can write Java programs that can compile Java code.

Comment: and can i compile C, C++ in this too, that was the main reason i was asking for the method to manipulate cmd.

Comment: Oh, it was not clear for me that you wanted to compile C/C++ code using Java! I assumed that you were interested in compiling Java code.